# Python Groupby keys list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following for instance:

```
x = [{'A':1},{'A':1},{'A':2},{'B':1},{'B':1},{'B':2},{'B':3},{'C':1},{'D':1}]
```

and I would like to get a dictionary like this:

```
x = [{'A': [1,2], 'B': [1,2,3], 'C':[1], 'D': [1]}]
```

Do you have any idea how I could get this please?

Comment: I wonder where do you get such data. It's very a bad design and I can't think of any scenario where such data structure is needed. If you are creating it, why don't you create it like the second one in the first place? It makes more sense.

Comment: webscraping, getting words and storing urls, so words can be used several times in the same url... If you have a better idea, I'm listening too though :)

Comment: So my second question arises: if it is *you* who created the first `x`, why don't you make it like in the second one? You can even get rid of the additional list which serves no purpose but just makes your life harder.

Comment: Okay. I am counting occurrences of words. I have a dataframe like:
'date', 'words', 'url'
date1, {'A':3, 'B':4...}, url1
date2, {...}, url2. And in url I have several days

Comment: Create an empty `dict` and whenever you get a key like `'A'` check if it is in your dictionary. If it is, append the value else create a new list with your value in it: `if key in my_dict: my_dict[key].append(value) else: my_dict[key]=[value]`

Comment: I might also do like this yea. I will check this option too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
x = [{'A':1},{'A':1},{'A':2},{'B':1},{'B':1},{'B':2},{'B':3},{'C':1},{'D':1}]
res = {}
for i in x:
    for k, v in i.items():
        res.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)

#or res = [{k: list(v) for k, v in res.items()}]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': {1, 2}, 'B': {1, 2, 3}, 'C': {1}, 'D': {1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of sets to collect unique values, then convert the final result to a dictionary with values as lists using a dict comprehension:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'A':1},{'A':1},{'A':2},{'B':1},{'B':1},{'B':2},{'B':3},{'C':1},{'D':1}]

result = defaultdict(set)
for dic in lst:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        result[key].add(value)

print({key: list(value) for key, value in result.items()})
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [1], 'D': [1]}
```

Although its probably better to add your data directly to the `defaultdict` to begin with, instead of creating a list of singleton dictionaries(don't recommend this data structure) then converting the result.